# How to deploy servlet java maven web application to cloud run?

Tags: java, docker, maven, google-cloud-run

I successfully deployed spring boot web application to cloud run and its working fine.

But I could not deploy a servlet based maven java web application to cloud run.

when i run this command "**gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/gcloud-myapp/sample**"
i am getting

> Deployment failed ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error:
> Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port
> defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might
> contain more information.

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official maven/Java 8 image to create a build artifact.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/maven
FROM maven:3.8-jdk-11 as builder

# Copy local code to the container image.

    WORKDIR /app
    COPY pom.xml .
    COPY src ./src
    
    # Build a release artifact.
    RUN mvn package -DskipTests
    
    # Use AdoptOpenJDK for base image.
    # It's important to use OpenJDK 8u191 or above that has container support enabled.
    # https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8
    # https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
    FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-slim
    
    # Copy the jar to the production image from the builder stage.
    COPY --from=builder /app/target/sample*.war /sample.war
    
    EXPOSE 8080
    
    # Run the web service on container startup.
    CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/sample.war","--host", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "8080"]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>in.com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is it possible to deploy servlet based maven java web application to cloud run?

Comment: Are you able to start your server locally (with the java command)? If so, are you able to run the container locally?

Comment: My guess is, your container image needs to be fixed.  As you got this same exact error, I would like you to go through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start) check out all the possibilities and rule them out if you are doing it right. Revert with the findings.

Comment: @Pamba Any update? Did you look over the documentation I referred? Was your issue resolved? If not, we can further continue until we get the resolution.

Comment: @Priyashree Bhadra Thank you for the support. Yes I referred the documentation. But I couldn't resolve the issue.  I am thinking about changing this project to a Spring Boot

Comment: @Pamba I will share an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/java-frameworks-performances-on-cloud-run-eb243fd84a5c) by guillaume blaquiere where he has mentioned the different Java frameworks and how they work with Cloud Run. I suggest you go to this [GitHub page](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/cloudrun-java-framework), clone the sample from servlet framework, try it on your end. If the deployment is successful, we will know there is something faulty at your end. Else we may have to file a bug with Cloud Run not performing well with Java Servlet apps.

Comment: Also please share detailed logs from the failed deployment. Use [strace](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting/tracing-system-calls) and revert with the findings.

Comment: @Pamba Any update? Did you try those?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this question, I will share an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/java-frameworks-performances-on-cloud-run-eb243fd84a5c) by guillaume blaquiere where he has mentioned the different Java frameworks and how they work with Cloud Run. I suggest you go to this [GitHub page](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/cloudrun-java-framework), clone the sample for the servlet framework and try it on your end. If the deployment is successful, we will know there is something faulty at your end. Else we may have to file a bug with Cloud Run not performing well with Java Servlet apps [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0).